# error using `this` in intilization list

Tags: c++

I get the error "expected identifier" for the following code. How do I use initilization lists properly in constructors?

```
tanVec::tanVec(const int x, const int y, const int z): this->x(x), this->y(y), this->z(z)
{

}
```

Comment: Just remove `this->` you don't need it (make the parameter names differ from your member variables, by for example adding _). [Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e2ee1d96d95e747b)

Comment: I don't think you even need to make the names different with an initialization list.

Comment: You don't have to make your constructor parameter names different from member names. `C::C(int x) : x(x) {}` is perfectly valid.

Comment: @user2357112 Yes, I should have specified that part is optional. I just think it makes it clearer. Maybe that's just me.

Comment: @moswald is that valid just for initialization lists or even if it were in the body of the constructor?

Comment: @Celeritas: In the body, you need `this->`.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman not entirely true. The memory has been allocated and there is a valid address for `this`; if you need to, you can access previously-initialized members safely: `struct Foo { int x; int y; Foo() : x(0), y(x) {} };`

Answer (score 3):

You can safely remove `this` - it is not needed for disambiguation, because the names in the initialization list are resolved to members of your class, even if your argument list has parameters with names that would require disambiguation in the body of the constructor.

```
// Compiler will not confuse members x, y, and z with constructor arguments x, y, and z
tanVec::tanVec(const int x, const int y, const int z): x(x), y(y), z(z) {}
```

[Small demo on ideone.](http://ideone.com/criIGW)